# How to modal the view when network connecting

Tags: three20, presentmodalviewcontroller

Is there any way to set the view page modal during network connecting? I mean all controllers in page do not response the user operation if the network is connecting?

---

I updated code like:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];
    _hudView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, 155, 170, 170)];
    _hudView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5];
    _hudView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    _hudView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;

    _activityIndicatorView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    _activityIndicatorView.frame = CGRectMake(65, 40, _activityIndicatorView.bounds.size.width, _activityIndicatorView.bounds.size.height);
    [_hudView addSubview:_activityIndicatorView];
    [_activityIndicatorView startAnimating];

    _captionLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 115, 130, 22)];
    _captionLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    _captionLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    _captionLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    _captionLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    _captionLabel.text = @"Loading...";
    [_hudView addSubview:_captionLabel];



    NSArray *buttonNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"hehe",@"xixi",nil];

    UISegmentedControl *segmentControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:buttonNames];
    segmentControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, TTApplicationFrame().size.width/2, TT_ROW_HEIGHT-10); 
    segmentControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    segmentControl.momentary = NO;
    segmentControl.tintColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor]; 
    segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
    [segmentControl addTarget:self action:@selector(switchPage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = segmentControl;
    TT_RELEASE_SAFELY(segmentControl);
    self.view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:TTApplicationFrame()] autorelease];
    self.tableView = [[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:TTApplicationFrame() style:UITableViewStylePlain] autorelease];
    self.tableView.rowHeight = 80.f;
    self.tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
    [self reload]; 
    [self updateView]; 
}
```

and show it like:

```
- (void)showLoading:(BOOL)show {
    if (show) {
        self.loadingView = _hudView;

    }
    else {        
        self.loadingView = nil;

    }
}
```

As I said in comment, it still cannot cover the buttons of UISegmentedControl, user still can click those buttons...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a modalViewController, create a HUD (one of the nice views with a UIActivityIndicators you'll see in the TTCatalogue app) that will block the view and inform the user something is happening while you're making a request.
Just insert them by a `[self.view addSubview:theHUDview];`.

It's not necessarily good design though, instead, make your network calls asynchronously, in the background.

Comment: Thanks buddy, it really helped! But my case is: the data start load by response the buttons click action, and the buttons are lay on navigator UISegmentedControl, so the UIActivityIndicators could not cover those buttons, they still can be clicked during the network connecting...

Comment: OK, I understand.  Well, nothing prevent you from showing a modal ViewController that is entirely made out of a semi-transparent / transparent view with a hud in the middle.